# Acessing javaScript array of objects like a matrix

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

Is it possible to make access to a property of an object into an array of objects like a matrix?

I mean something like this:

**jSon generated object:**

```
[
    {
        "Nome": "1",
        "Departamento": "1",
        "Cargo": "1"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "5",
        "Departamento": "5",
        "Cargo": "5"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "2",
        "Departamento": "2",
        "Cargo": "2"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "3",
        "Departamento": "33",
        "Cargo": "33"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "4",
        "Departamento": "4",
        "Cargo": "4"
    }
]
```

**How I'm trying access the object properties:**

```
object[0][1] = value;
```

**What I already do:**

```
object[0]["Nome"] = value;
```

I've searched a lot, but I can't find a solution for this problem.

Comment: You can't access an object's property in the same way you do an array's index (which is what it appears you're trying to do).  If you need to use indexes to access the values, I'd suggest converting those objects to arrays.

Comment: How can I do this conversion? Can I convert the array into a matrix and then back to an array of objects?

Comment: @Wellington: What do you need the matrix for? What should happen to the property names (they're not included in the matrix so converting back is complicated)? In what order do you want the items' values to be, currently the objects are unordered?

Comment: If you do need to do the conversion, you can do it with something like this: http://jsbin.com/aruhud/2/edit

Comment: @Bergi: My object is in a hidden field in my form, I refresh one HTML table with this values, each object in a row, each property in a cell. I'm trying to make a function to edit these values in the HTML table and then update the hidden field with the jSon object. 
The difficulty here is that I'm need to make this function more generic as possible, for make it reusable in the entire system.

Comment: @Wellington: But you don't need a matrix for that, your current structure is totally fine. Of course, a CSV-like structure with additional header information (and column order) would work as well, yet it is not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Objects and Arrays are two very different types in JavaScript. In an Array order is very important but order is not retained for Object keys. Keep in mind you can still iterate over the keys of an Object.

```
for (var prop in myObj) {
  console.log("myObj.prop -> ", myObj[prop]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As already stated, [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)s and [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)s are different. I don't really follow your reasoning for converting from one structure to the other, and you should probably consider working in a different way, which is totally possible from your question and comment descriptions. But, if you really must convert then you will need to perform some kind of mapping, to and from, to be sure that things are ordered correctly. You could do something like this.

Javascript

```
function toMapped (array) {
    var mapping = {
            "Nome": 0,
            "Departamento": 1,
            "Cargo": 2
        },
        mapped = [],
        length = array.length,
        i = 0,
        element,
        j;

    while (i < length ) {
        element = [];

        for (j in mapping) {
            if (mapping.hasOwnProperty(j) && array[i].hasOwnProperty(j)) {
                element[mapping[j]] = array[i][j];
            }
        }

        mapped.push(element);
        i += 1;
    }

    return mapped;
}

function fromMapped (array) {
    var mapping = {
            0: "Nome",
            1: "Departamento",
            2: "Cargo"
        },
        mapped = [],
        length = array.length,
        i = 0,
        object,
        j;

    while (i < length ) {
        object = {};
        for (j in mapping) {
            if (mapping.hasOwnProperty(j) && array[i].hasOwnProperty(j)) {
                object[mapping[j]] = array[i][j];
            }
        }

        mapped.push(object);
        i += 1;
    }

    return mapped;
}

var test = [{
    "Nome": "1",
    "Departamento": "1",
    "Cargo": "1"
}, {
    "Nome": "5",
    "Departamento": "5",
    "Cargo": "5"
}, {
    "Nome": "2",
    "Departamento": "2",
    "Cargo": "2"
}, {
    "Nome": "3",
    "Departamento": "33",
    "Cargo": "33"
}, {
    "Nome": "4",
    "Departamento": "4",
    "Cargo": "4"
}];

var mapped = toMapped(test);
var unmapped = fromMapped(mapped);

console.log(test);
console.log(mapped);
console.log(unmapped);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/hrdLA/)

Using ECMA5 [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Javascript

```
function toMapped(array) {
    var mapping = {
        "Nome": 0,
        "Departamento": 1,
        "Cargo": 2
    };

    return array.map(function (object) {
        var element = [],
            i;

        for (i in mapping) {
            if (mapping.hasOwnProperty(i) && object.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                element[mapping[i]] = object[i];
            }
        }

        return element;
    });
}

function fromMapped(array) {
    var mapping = {
        0: "Nome",
        1: "Departamento",
        2: "Cargo"
    };

    return array.map(function (element) {
        var object = {},
            i;

        for (i in mapping) {
            if (mapping.hasOwnProperty(i) && element.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                object[mapping[i]] = element[i];
            }
        }

        return object;
    });
}

var test = [{
    "Nome": "1",
        "Departamento": "1",
        "Cargo": "1"
}, {
    "Nome": "5",
        "Departamento": "5",
        "Cargo": "5"
}, {
    "Nome": "2",
        "Departamento": "2",
        "Cargo": "2"
}, {
    "Nome": "3",
        "Departamento": "33",
        "Cargo": "33"
}, {
    "Nome": "4",
        "Departamento": "4",
        "Cargo": "4"
}];

var mapped = toMapped(test);
var unmapped = fromMapped(mapped);

console.log(test);
console.log(mapped);
console.log(unmapped);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/rTqKb/)

Comment: I'd recommend to just iterate/enumerate over the `mapping` instead of the `object`/`subarray`. Also, you really really should use the `map` function instead of `forEach`…

Comment: Of course it can be done in many ways, I would normally have used `while`, for cross-browser compatibility in such examples, but was a little lazy/short of time so used `forEach`. But sure `map` would also have been appropriate for ECMA5 methods.

Comment: @Bergi Updated with your suggestions.